# Ubuntu 18.04: PCI WLAN can't connect after upgrade

Tags: networking, network-manager, 18.04, lenovo

I recently upgraded my PC's(Lenovo ideapad 100) OS from Ubuntu 17.04 to 18.04 and since It can't connect anymore to Wifi-Networks using the inbuilt PCI adapter -- using a USB-adapter works fine but is not the solution I'm content with.
What is strange is that it can find the networks (so the drivers seem to work) but when trying to connect it can't activate the connection.
I tried connecting to different Wifi-networks and it didn't work connecting to any, so I guess the network itself is not the problem.

It would be great if anyone had some advice or if there were people with similar problems who were able to solve them!
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to it?

Comment: Yes but no. I know now, that it works just fine in japanese networks, but not in european networks.
My best guess would be, that it has something to do with the security settings of the network.